# c# UI Automation for OpenGL

Tags: selenium, opengl, ui-automation

Is it possible to inspect GUI elements for OpenGL windows applications, as it is possible to do it with native windows apps or any app done in WPF or windows forms? I would like to be able to read text of labels, textboxes in the OpenGL application, didn't manage to do it with UIAutomation with c#, nor with Selenium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. OpenGL is a rasterisation API: by the time the UI element data reaches OpenGL, it is already in a format describing how to draw rectangles and the pixels of the font, not abstract UI element descriptions.

Your best bet is OCR.